# Changing decorator arguments in sub-classes

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-decorators

Not sure if this is even a proper question but here's the problem.

I have a memoized decorator (implemented as a class). The decorator takes an argument that is the size of the cache. I want my DB model classes to each have a search method so I write a mixin (I think it is a mixin)

```
class SearchMixin(object): 
    @classmethod
    @memoized(100)
    def search(cls,session,**kwargs): 
        q = session.query(cls)
        for k,v in kwargs.items(): 
            q = q.filter(getattr(cls,k,None).__eq__(v))
        res = q.one()
        return res
```

And in my models,

```
class ModelA(Base,SearchMixin): 
    foo = Column()
    bar = Column() 
    #And so on
```

Now I can do a `ModelA.search(foo=x,bar=y)` and the memoized decorator works and returns from the cache if the same query has been asked before.

The problem is that for some models I need to change the size of cache for some searches (which is by defualt `100` in the `SearchMixin`). I can re-write the search function with a different argument to the decorator

```
class ModelB(Base): 
    @classmethod
    @memoized(5)
    def search(cls,session,**kwargs): 
        #Search method for my modelB
```

but that defeats the purpose of writing the mixin (removing code duplication).

What I'd ideally want is

```
class ModelB(Base,SearchMxin): 
    foo1 = Column()
    bar1 = Column()
    cache_size = 5 
    #Some magic
    #Now I don't need to rewrite the search function with a different argument
```

Is there any way of achieving this? Is it even a valid way of use?

Comment: You could do it by writing a different memoization decorator that reads its cache size from a class attribute when it's called, instead reading it from an argument when it's defined.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sketch of one way:

```
def deco(func):
    def newFunc(cls, *args, **kw):
        print "Decorated function using cache size", cls.cache_size
        return func(cls, *args, **kw)
    return newFunc

class Foo(object):
    cache_size = 10

    @classmethod
    @deco
    def meth(cls):
        print "Foo.meth()"

class Bar(Foo):
    cache_size = 20

>>> Foo.meth()
Decorated function using cache size 10
Foo.meth()
>>> Bar.meth()
Decorated function using cache size 20
Foo.meth()
```

I don't know exactly what your memoization decorator does, so this example just uses a dummy decorator.  But the idea should be clear: write your decorator so that it looks on the class for its cache size, instead of passing the cache size as an argument.

Just to clarify something: in your example, when you create the `search` method on `SearchMixin` and apply `@memoize(100)`, the "original" search method --- that is, the undecorated version with no memoization --- effectively no longer exists.  If the cache size is fixed at the time of the decorator call, you can't reach back inside and alter it later just by assigning a class variable.  Ultimately, you need to somehow refactor the decorator so that it retrieves the desired cache size from some external source (e.g., the class).

(If your memoization decorator is actually a class, it might be possible to make it smarter and sneakier, so that it would notice if it were "redecorating" a method that had already been wrapped with the same decorator.  In such a case, the memoization class could modify its internal cache size variable instead of adding another layer of wrapping.  However, it's hard to say exactly how this would work, or how it would interact with other decorators, without knowing something about how your memoization decorator currently operates.)

Comment: That's a good idea. But my decorator is a class (not a function) and accepts a few more parameters (debugging and stuff). It can be used on arbitrary functions as well (not just class methods). Currently I do not pass the class to the decorator (Just the function)

Comment: @RedBaron: If you have other restrictions on your decorator, you'll need to edit your question to explain them.  The solution I gave here could easily be done using a class instead of a function, and could accept extra parameters.  However, I don't think there's much hope of writing a decorator that works for class methods and standalone functions, but still looks on the class to find out its cache size.  If you want the decorator to make use of a class variable like `cache_size`, the decorator needs to have some degree of integration with the class.